# How to keep os.execute(...) window open in Lua?

Tags: cmd, lua

I have a simple Lua project that runs a NodeJS script every few minutes. The NodeJS script sets a function Interval and makes a request to an API every second or so.

My Lua looks like this:

```lua
function Initialize()
    Running = false
end

function Update()
    if not Running then
        Running = true
        os.execute(table.concat({"npm", "i"}, " "))
        os.execute(table.concat({"npm", "start"}, " "))
    end
end
```

How do I keep the Command Prompt window that opens with `os.execute()` open? It closes after the command is finished but I want to see the output before it closes. No, I don't want the result in my Lua code, I'd just like to see the window.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: I'm Running on Windows 10

Comment: The usage of [os.execute](http://lua-users.org/wiki/OsLibraryTutorial) in LUA is like using function [system](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) in C or C++. It means executed is on Windows the Windows command processor `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` with option `/c` to close the command process after finishing the execution of command line and the command line defined in the LUA script appended as additional arguments. So the first `os.execute` results in execution of `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c npm i` and the second in `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c npm start`.

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `cmd /?` and read the output help. There is explained how the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` interprets the argument string(s) after option `/C` or option `/K` which would result in keeping command processor running after finishing the execution of the specified command line. In the command prompt window run `where npm` and output is the full qualified file name. You can see that `npm` is on Windows `npm.cmd`, a batch file which is very important to know.

Comment: What you want to execute with `os.execute` is something like `start "NPM" %ComSpec% /D /E:ON /K "call npm.cmd i & call npm.cmd start"`. That looks crazy and it is. There is started the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` with option `/c` by `os.execute` to execute a command line with its internal command `start` to start one more command process with a new console window with title `NPM` with ignoring the `AutoRun` registry value and with command extensions enabled to call two times `npm.cmd` with keeping this second command process running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
os.execute([[start "NPM" %ComSpec% /D /E:ON /K "call npm.cmd i & call npm.cmd start"]])
```

(based on Mofi's code)

Runs `npm i` and `npm start` sequentially on the same window

```
os.execute([[start "npm i" %ComSpec% /D /E:ON /K "call npm.cmd i"]])
os.execute([[start "npm start" %ComSpec% /D /E:ON /K "call npm.cmd start"]])
```

Runs `npm i` and `npm start` sequentially on separate windows.

Explanation: `[[` is to escape quotes and lua sequences. `start` runs command window with some options and executes "npm i".

I am not sure if `call` and `.cmd` are necessary (it runs without), but I've kept on Mofi recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for this! It works without the Batchfile, which is really helpful :)